# where do I get a key for google-translate?

Tags: google-translate, google-ajax-api

It appears that to use Google Translate you have to use an API key but I can't find anywhere where do I get the key. Is the key the same used for the search APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a search API key should work, though isn't required, according to the docs http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/ (I read a bit of the docs a while back, but never did get into my idea for using it, so there could well be a difference between the theory and practice that I didn't find).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use Referer or UserIP address. Once you enter your IP address, you may access the Google Translate IP.